# Why dompdf does not recognize images?

Tags: image, dompdf

this is the html code from the pdf :

```
  <img src="http://netprojects/images/antet.png" alt="poza" />
  <img src="../images/antet.png" alt="poza" />
  <img src="./images/antet.png" alt="poza" />
  <img src="/images/antet.png" alt="poza" />
  <img src="http://np.netlogiq.org//images/antet.png" alt="poza" />
```

as you can see I tried every possible way

from the dompdf_config_inc.php the dompdf_enable_remote is set to true:

```
define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", true);
```

What else can i try?

Comment: Do you see any error message from PHP or your web server in the logs? What about other image formats (e.g. JPG)? Do you have GD enabled (required with 0.6.0 to process PNG images)? Is the directory specified by `DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR` writable?

Comment: actually i changed the current version of dompdf to an oldest version and it works, don't ask me why :) , thx for the answer :)

Comment: It's probably the GD requirement. I believe the older version didn't require GD for most image processing.

Comment: sometimes the oldest version is better then the new one

Comment: Depends on your requirements. There is much better support for characters outside the Windows ANSI character set and a number of updates to CSS support. But certainly if the older one works you are welcome to use it. Just be aware that there is a [security issues in 0.6.0](https://www.portcullis-security.com/security-research-and-downloads/security-advisories/cve-2014-2383/) that probably affects 0.5.x.